# How to convert word to word using perl?

Tags: perl, ms-word

I am new to perl script.... I need to convert doc to doc because i will text changes in original doc so how to start this conversion using perl script, I tried to convert to html and change that text and html file convert to doc... But I don't know how can i start this and how can i convert using perl?

```
input :

Orginal.doc

sample bold text

output.doc

sample italic text
```

how to convert this situations? ....using perl script..

I think other idea: **doc to html and html to doc**

Comment: When you say "doc", do you mean a Microsoft word document?

Comment: sorry for happen... yes I mean Microsoft word document...

Comment: I don't know, but you could try this as a starting point: http://www.wellho.net/solutions/perl-using-perl-to-read-microsoft-word-documents.html

Comment: yes that site use to write word document, i want to change text orginal.doc file and save output.doc....

Answer (score 1):

I don't have clear answer for you...

But It may be usefull for you...
Visit this Cpan page...

[`Win32::Word::Writer`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32%3a%3aWord%3a%3aWriter)

Answer (score 0):

Just edit directly using [`Win32::OLE`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32%3a%3aOLE).

The following is a useful example of loading an existing word doc and saving it to a new file after changes: [`A Solution to the edit Word documents with Perl problem`](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=733792).  Btw, one could find this by simply googling: [`editing a word doc using perl`](https://www.google.com/search?q=editing+a+word+doc+using+perl)